# rosdoc_lite issues

Tags: ros, rosdoc, documentation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As rosdoc is deprecated, we've recently switched from rosdoc to rosdoc_lite for our private, internal documentation of not-ready-for-primetime packages.

But the web docs created by rosdoc_lite seem to ignore the (private) URLs in our manifest.xml files and just default to ros.org/wiki/ for all packages.

So, we are debating going back to dependable rosdoc, unless of course there are some undocumented tricks for rosdoc_lite that will help us out.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54785/rosdoc_lite-issues/) by [pbeeson](https://answers.ros.org/users/695/pbeeson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 276 on 2013-02-08

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I agree that rosdoc-lite should honor the URL specified, and not default to ros.org/wiki, even if that is the usual case.

I recommend [opening a rsodoc_lite issue](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdoc_lite/issues) to get it fixed.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Patrick, I know this is a really old question but I recently had the same issue and it seems you can specify options such as this via yaml (see Section 2.3.2 [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rosdoc_lite)).  Long story short, to change the linked website in the documentation just make a `rosdoc.yaml` file in the root directory of your package that contains the following:

```
- builder: doxygen
  homepage: https://my.private.url.com
```

---

Originally posted by [BrettHemes](https://answers.ros.org/users/20527/bretthemes/) with karma: 525 on 2017-10-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [diogoa](https://answers.ros.org/users/30827/diogoa/) on 2018-07-17**:
This answer still holds at the moment I'm writing this.